# After Google+ People API list endpoint is deprecated. It is possible to get the visible friends list in circle?

Tags: api, google-api, google-people-api

Using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" api, we are getting the  access to a list of people in the user's circles in addition to their name and profile information. After api deprecation, we using people.connections.list api  "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections" as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?authuser=1) but we get list contacts only, not friends list in google+. please help us to retrieve the friends list in google-plus. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably only telling you what you already know or have guessed.

From the [deprecated People API page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve-a-collection-of-people): "... calls to the API return empty circle data for those new sign-ins." and "In place of the social connection data from the Google+ People API, you can get rich *contacts* data from the new Google People API."

It seems that there will no longer be a public API for getting a Google+ friends list.  Consider supporting an alternate social media platform for your app or utilizing Google Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/) will actually be more powerful than the G+ people.list method. The G+ API only listed people that the user had circled--that isn't the same as being a friend or close contact. The people API likely better reflects closer connections between individuals as well as exposing a broad number of contacts to apps. I think for most apps, this is an improvement.

Comment: how can i get friends list by when we use or connected with the same app using the people.list api? and If the contact id is the global  unique id or not?.

Comment: Is there a way to ask Google about People API ? Some Google Groups page? I have a question about it, as I've noticed some classes were deprecated and/or removed  (`com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential` and `com.google.api.services.people.v1.People.Builder` for example) .